# How to find out if serial port is closed?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am working on a multi threaded server application for processing serial/USB ports.

The issue is that if a cable gets unplugged, pyserial keeps reporting that the port is open and available. When reading I only receive `Empty` exceptions (due to read timeout).

How do I find out that a port has been disconnected so that I can handle this case?

Edit: OS is Ubuntu 12.04

Edit 2: Clarification - I am connecting to serial port devices via Serial to USB connector, thus the device being disconnected is an USB device.

Comment: on linux you can just use `dmesg` for this kind of tasks

Comment: I need a solution that works within my Python application, so that I can shutdown the whole process if a port goes missing.

Comment: it will works on your python app. for instance pseudo code: `while(subprocess(dmesg | tail "any grep params")): do`

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: That could work, yet it doesn't feel kosher enough. Especially since dmesg specifies driver inf/ttyUSB not the linked port name (which is only deterministic piece of information I have available).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Serial port has no real concept of "cable connected" or not connected.

Depending on the equipment you are using you could try to poll the DSR or CTS lines, and decide there is no device connected when those stay low over a certain time.

From wikipedia:

> DTR and DSR are usually on all the time and, per the RS-232 standard
>   and its successors, are used to signal from each end that the other
>   equipment is actually present and powered-up

So if you've got a conforming device, the DSR line could be the thing you need.

Edit:
As you seem to use an USB2Serial converter, you can try to check whether the device node still exists - you don't need to try to open it.

so os.path.exists(devNode)  could suffice.

Comment: It's interesting that OS knows when a device is connected (/dev/ttyUSBX) and I am using fixed symlink for each device (e.g.: /dev/mycustomLink) and when the cable gets disconnected, OS knows it and removes device from the list. Thus I would be happy with an elegant way of polling the OS on device status (is it present or absent)

Comment: @JanezStupar What you describe here is what happens when the USB plug is pulled. That can be detected. This answer describes what happens if the RS232 plug is pulled.

Comment: Ah. You're talking about an USB device here; you would need an usb library then to poll the presence of that device.

Otherwise you could simply poll whether the device node (/dev/ttyUSBx you opened in the beginning) is still available, this culd suffice in your case?

Comment: @user1442158: So how do I go about polling the device in a sane manner? Just try to open new connections or something else?

Comment: @JanezStupar: Try wheter /dev/ttyUSB0  still exists (whether you can stat that file) - if it does, the usb 2 serial converter should still be attached.

You can't detect whether the serial part of the cable has been removed with that test, though; the DSR line could provide you that information